# Boost Json with null elements

Tags: c++, json, boost, null

I'm trying to use boost ptree with boost json parser. When generating a json message, I can set a value to true or false and compile the program.

Which keyword is used for null? I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none. Outputting nulls is not supported. Outputting booleans isn't either. All values are outputted as strings, period.

From `json_parser_write.hpp`:

```
    // Value or object or array
    if (indent > 0 && pt.empty())
    {
        // Write value
        Str data = create_escapes(pt.template get_value<Str>());
        stream << Ch('"') << data << Ch('"');

    }
```