# How to check a value for null when using boost json ptree

Tags: c++, json, boost, null

I 'm getting a json response from a server of the following format :

```
{"value": 98.3}
```

However there are cases that the response can be :

```
{"value": null}
```

I have written a C++ program that uses boost json in order to parse this and get the value as float

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>



using namespace std;
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     try
     {
          float valuef;
          pt::ptree root;
          std::stringstream ss;
          string result;
          std::ifstream file("test.json");

          if (file)
          {
               ss << file.rdbuf();

               file.close();
          }
          pt::read_json(ss, root);
          auto value  = root.get<string>("value");
          if (value != "null")
          {
               valuef = stof(value);
          }
          cout <<"float value is" << valuef << endl;

     }

     catch (std::exception &e)
     {
          string err = e.what();
          cout << "error is " << endl
               << err << endl;
     }
}
```

So I always check if the value is not equal with the literal "null" because according to this
[Boost Json with null elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343292/boost-json-with-null-elements)
outputting nulls is not supported.
Since the post is 7 years old I was wondering whether the latest boost libraries support something more generic to check for null values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp` you can only check the string version like you said:

> So I always check if the value is not equal with the literal "null" because according to this
> [Boost Json with null elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343292/boost-json-with-null-elements) outputting nulls is not supported.

However, since [boost version 1.75.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html), you can also use `boost/json.hpp` for working with JSON objects.

A parsed JSON object is now of type `json::value` and the types are specified with `json::kind`. See [boost.org's example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/examples.html).

Thus, with the [value](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/dom/value.html) you would be able to do something like:

```cpp
// jv is a value from a kvp-pair
if(jv.is_null()) {
 // Json value is null
}
```

Refer to the boost's example for the implementation specifics.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting using a proper JSON library!

Answer (score 1):

No. From [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser):

> JSON values are mapped to nodes containing the value. However, all type information is lost; numbers, as well as **the literals "null", "true" and "false" are simply mapped to their string form**.